# Autoindent PHP Array in Notepad++?

Tags: php, notepad++

I'm currently having difficulty with auto-indenting PHP arrays that span multiple lines. The standard TextFX > TextFX Edit > Reindent C++ Code fails here.

For example, take the following code snippet:

```
<?php
$something = array(
    "test" => $var,
    "nested" => array(
        "subnest" = array(
            "low" => "yes",
            "foo" => "bar",
            ),
        "bar" => "baz",
        ),
    "last" => "yes",
    );
```

Run "Reindent C++ Code" and get this:

```
<?php
$something = array(
"test" => $var,
"nested" => array(
"subnest" = array(
"low" => "yes",
"foo" => "bar",
),
"bar" => "baz",
),
"last" => "yes",
);
```

Not really what I was after.

Is there any tool I'm missing or plugin that can properly indent PHP arrays in Notepad++?

Comment: Use Netbeans http://www.netbeans.com

Comment: How the heck is this off topic? IDE questions have long been asked on SO. Just look at the notepad++ tag.

Comment: @Petah While I love Netbeans there are many times when I need something... lighter.

Comment: what exact formatting are you after?  As in your code snippet, or...?

Comment: @bob-the-destroyer I'm after having Np++ indent this code snippet correctly (The first one is actually what I'm after but Np++ reformats it like the second one). The issue is in large PHP files everything indents correctly except this, preventing me from using it all the time.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, still (*at the time of this writing*) Notepad++ doesn't have support for code indentation formatting of anything other than curly brace `{}` blocks, in PHP and most other languages it supports.

`switch` is another one:

```
switch ($value) {
    case 1:
        foo();
        break;
    case 2:
        bar();
        break;
    case 3:
        qux();
        break;
}
```

Becomes:

```
switch ($value) {
    case 1:
    foo();
    break;
    case 2:
    bar();
    break;
    case 3:
    qux();
    break;
}
```

The solution I've found (*at least with PHP*) is to use curly braces for formatting, as they are syntactically valid yet don't change the program structure:

```
switch ($value) {
    case 1: {
        foo();
        break;
    }
    case 2: {
        bar();
        break;
    }
    case 3: {
        qux();
        break;
    }
}
```

This has the added bonus of allowing you to code-fold arbitrary blocks of your script.

Unfortunately as you've discovered, square `[]` and round `()` brackets aren't recognized by the formatter, and arrays wouldn't be a syntactically valid case for curly brace wrapping.

Short answer being; sorry, I've tried exhaustively too, you'll need to find/write a plugin (*I haven't; I just live with it*)

Answer (score 0):

There was an error in your code - that could have been causing it. Netbeans showed me this error and then I fixed it.

Try changing this line:

```
"nested" = array(
```

to

```
"nested" => array(
```

and see how Notepad++ handles it.

I used netbeans for this, even if I am writing in another application, I copy and paste it to netbeans to tidy it up.

[Netbeans](http://netbeans.com/)

Netbeans returns:

```
<?php

$something = array(
    "test" => $var,
    "nested" => array(
        "subnest" => array(
            "low" => "yes",
            "foo" => "bar",
        ), "bar" => "baz",),
    "last" => "yes",
);
?>
```

Comment: That was more of an example than actual code. But I did make the change, no difference. And as I said to @Petah, I use Np++ most of the time since I need something lighter.

Comment: Possibly the reason its lighter is due to the fact it doesn't have a powerful code formatter. I use Coda for most of my development and it has a horrible formatter plugin.